# How to separate plots from subplots and plot correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
I am trying to plot the following sample table:
```

| Time Period | HR | Legal | Fin | Leadership | Market | UX | CX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/04/2021 | 6.39 | 5.81 | 7.53 | 7.16 | 6.78 | 7.25 | 7.40 | 7.47 | 6.20 |
| 01/07/2021 | 6.95 | 6.25 | 7.46 | 7.16 | 7.05 | 7.51 | 7.70 | 7.83 | 6.69 |
| 01/10/2021 | 7.41 | 6.43 | 7.65 | 7.50 | 7.25 | 7.74 | 8.00 | 8.04 | 6.90 |
| 01/01/2022 | 7.51 | 6.51 | 7.74 | 7.52 | 8.00 | 7.84 | 8.10 | 8.04 | 7.05 |
| 01/04/2022 | 7.70 | 6.91 | 7.86 | 7.59 | 7.69 | 7.81 | 8.13 | 8.47 | 7.30 |
| 01/07/2022 | 7.80 | 6.60 | 7.50 | 7.50 | 7.80 | 7.50 | 7.70 | 7.90 | 7.15 |

```
(Please note there are 11 columns but all of them cannot be included)
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels.api as sm
import warnings

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode,  plot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

'set filepath'

data = pd.read_csv(inputfilepath, parse_dates=["Time Period"], index_col = "Time Period")

print(data.shape)

'Convert column from object to datetime'

#data["Time Period"] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time Period'], format="%d/%m/%Y")

data

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, dpi=110, figsize=(10,6))
#axes.axis("off")
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    macro_data = data[data.columns[i]]
    ax.plot(data, color='red', linewidth=1)
    # Decorations
    ax.set_title(data.columns[i], fontsize = 10)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    ax.spines["top"].set_alpha(0)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=6)

plt.tight_layout();
```

I end up with 11 duplicated sub plots and each subplot has 11 lines across it. I want one line for each subplot to see each plot individually to compare. And, The plot is definitely wrong since the lines are not changing their gradients between each time period. Here is what I see:

[image: What I get]

And here is what I would (ideally want)[image: What I want]

For reference, I am using the guide found here:
https://github.com/nachi-hebbar/Multivariate-Time-Series-Forecasting/blob/main/VAR_Model%20(1).ipynb

Comment: You're plotting the whole data: ```ax.plot(data, color='red', linewidth=1)```

Comment: @fdireito That got the individual plots separated, thanks! Is there a way for the plotline to go through each point in the time period column?